# Responsive menu quickly close

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I have an issue with my responsive menu, when I click on the menu icon, it scrolls down and in a second it closes quickly. 
It's so strange because it happen in the main page, but in the rest of pages when I click on the menu, it scrolls down and it doesn´t close, so that´s a good point.

Anyone knows this is something common, or just a particular problem?

This is my header.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'language' ); ?>">

    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />

        <?php if (!is_404()) { include('inc/header_share.php'); } ?>

        <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>

        <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
        <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/css/ionicons.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/fonts/fonts.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/css/forms.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/css/owl.carousel.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/css/style.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />

        <link rel="icon" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />

        <?php wp_head(); ?>

    </head>

    <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

This is my home-page.php:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Home Page */ ?>

<?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/header.php'); ?>
<?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/nav/menu-sup.php'); ?>
<?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/varios/quick-contact.php'); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/home/slider.php'); ?>
            <div align="center">
    <a href="http://page.org/page/" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.page.org/wp-content/themes/page/images/22.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="http://www.page.org/pagecalendar" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.page.org/wp-content/themes/page/images/portal31.png" /></a> 
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/page.org/photos/?tab=album&album_id=168951596363636788" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.page.org/wp-content/themes/page/images/GOLF.png" /></a>
    <!--<a href="http://page.org/padel" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.page.org/wp-content/themes/page/images/PADELRESP.gif" /></a>-->
    <a href="http://page.org/no-category/forjm/#anchor/" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.page.org/wp-content/themes/page/images/bannerweb2.png" /></a>

</div>
            <?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/intros/home-intro.php'); ?>
            <?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/home/colaborate.php'); ?>
            <div align="center">
       <a href="http://www.radio.com" target="_blank"> <img src="http://www.page.org/wp-content/themes/page/images/radio3mobile.png" /></a>
      <!-- <a href="http://www.page.org/document_oficials/N1 Magazine.pdf" target="_blank"> <img src="http://www.page.org/wp-content/themes/page/images/magazinemobile.jpg" /></a>-->
      <a href="http://page.org/magazine/" target="_blank"> <img src="http://www.page.org/wp-content/themes/page/images/magazinemobile.jpg" /></a>
</div>
            <?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/home/loop-news.php'); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else: ?>
        <?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/vars/loop-void.php'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!--<?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/home/newsletter.php'); ?>-->

<?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/nav/menu-inf.php'); ?>  
<?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/footer.php'); ?>
```

And finally the style.css with the code that execute it:

```
.header-main { padding: 25px 20px 20px 20px; }
    .header-main .menu-trigger { display: block; float: left; width: 26px; height: 19px; background: url('../images/icons/menu.png') top center no-repeat; 
        background-size: contain; text-indent: -999999999px; overflow: hidden; margin-top: 5px; }
    .header-main .logo { display: none; float: right; width: 50%; height: 60px; background: url('../images/logo.png') top right no-repeat; 
        background-size: contain; text-indent: -999999999px; overflow: hidden; }

.menu-collapse-header { background: #464749; float: left; width: 100%; display: none; }
    .menu-collapse-header ul li a { background: #464749; color: #fff; padding: 15px; display: block; border-left: 8px solid #464749; }
    .menu-collapse-header ul li.current_page_item a { background: #57585a; border-left: 8px solid #57585a; }
    .menu-collapse-header ul li.current_page_ancestor a { background: #57585a; border-left: 8px solid #57585a; }
    .menu-collapse-header ul li a:hover {  background: #57585a; }
```

Comment: How could we can figured out the issue without looking on the scenario. Would you please provide us your site url so that we can look into it?

Comment: @MohammadAshiqueAli of course no problem, take a look to this site in your mobile! https://grupoenvera.org

Comment: Sure, will be checking now.

Comment: The issue is when the Hamburger menu is clicked it opens the menu and again it is being display none through JavaScript. Please share your JS code with us.

Comment: @MohammadAshiqueAli the .js code file it's very big and there are a lot of characters, how can I share it to you? Maybe by email?

Comment: Sure, you can share me on aliashiquemohammad@gmail.com or connect on FB https://www.facebook.com/aliashiquemohammad

Comment: @MohammadAshiqueAli there you have the JS file sent by email, I know it's a mess but not my fault.

Comment: Its a jQuery library you have send. Please look into email for my reply.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked it desktop and on mobile/android as well. In fact, on home page, hamburger menu is getting double trigger with one touch. Consider it like, one touch is opening it and another touch is closing it. There is some element which is overlapping hamburger partially so it's interrupting the touch functionality.

Please try these solutions:

1) CSS clearfix your elements, possibly it will fix straight away.

2) Check jQuery click event behind hamburger and make sure that it's being trigger only once, not twice. It will help you to cross check the problem and it can be fixed accordingly.